# Selenium scraper detected at loading first page

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

I'm trying yo scrape this site: https://www.zocdoc.com/

Frist I tried using request library and got this response from the site:

```
b'<html style="height:100%"><head><META NAME="ROBOTS" CONTENT="NOINDEX, NOFOLLOW"><meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no"><meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0"><meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1"></head><body style="margin:0px;height:100%"><iframe src="/_Incapsula_Resource?CWUDNSAI=20&xinfo=13-8874904-0%200NNN%20RT%281557792003687%20128%29%20q%280%20-1%20-1%20-1%29%20r%280%20-1%29%20B15%284%2c200%2c0%29%20U5&incident_id=787000970007113277-35368596172637725&edet=15&cinfo=04000000" frameborder=0 width="100%" height="100%" marginheight="0px" marginwidth="0px">Request unsuccessful. Incapsula incident ID: 787000970007113277-35368596172637725</iframe></body></html>'
```

Hence I switched to selenium which usually works. I using this simple code to test it:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
driver = webdriver.Chrome("/usr/lib/chromium-browser/chromedriver")
url = "https://www.zocdoc.com/"
driver.get(url)
```

But this is not working either, I'm getting this result:

[image]

How can be the site detecting that fast the robot?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the posted image suggests, the site is protected behind an Imperva WAF (Web Application Firewall) or a related product.

If you ping the site you'll see that all requests go through addresses related to Imperva.

```
ping www.zocdoc.com
Pinging ux639.x.incapdns.net [45.60.62.232] with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from 45.60.62.232: bytes=32 time=46ms TTL=59
Reply from 45.60.62.232: bytes=32 time=47ms TTL=59
Reply from 45.60.62.232: bytes=32 time=46ms TTL=59
Reply from 45.60.62.232: bytes=32 time=46ms TTL=59
```

As you can see, pinging **www.zocdoc.com** redirects you through an **incapdns.net** namespace, which according to [WHOIS](https://www.whois.com/whois/incapdns.net), is owned by Imperva Inc.

As for how the detection works. I believe that issue has been covered in the following post: [Can a website detect when you are using selenium with chromedriver?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33225947/can-a-website-detect-when-you-are-using-selenium-with-chromedriver) .

Comment: thanks, actually I solved it just putting a small delay and loading the site a second time, but I'm not sure why  it works.